# Lambda: module initialization error: Error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I'm getting this error when I deploy my Lambda function:

```
module initialization error: Error
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at bindings (/var/task/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:84:48)
at Object. (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:10:34)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

The serverless.yml and package.json:
https://github.com/A-Atrash/forfilesharingtohandleerror.
It's with Node. It used to work before I added a new package `ImageMagick` and started using it as an image validation. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're creating your Lambda package from non-Linux environment (e.g. Windows or MacOS).

`ImageMagick` uses native modules so you when you do your `npm install`, it compiles it for your current environment. If you're in Windows or MacOS, this compiled package will not work Lambda (which uses Linux).

For it to work, your Lambda package has to be created in a Linux environment and then uploaded from there.

Comment: Jeez! That's a log shot! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `source-map-support` package that discarded the actual error message and stack trace.
Once I commented out the `source-map-support` package import line then the error started showing the actual error message and stack trace.